# Advice with crawling web site content

Tags: java, web, web-crawler, web-scraping, jsoup

I was trying to crawl some of website content, using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) and java combination. Save the relevant details to my database and doing the same activity daily.

But here is the deal, when I open the website in browser I get rendered html (with all element tags out there). The javascript part when I test it, it works just fine (the one which I'm supposed to use to extract the correct data).

But when I do a parse/get with jsoup(from Java class), only the initial website is downloaded for parsing. Meaning there are some dynamic parts of a website and I want to get that data but since they're rendered post get, asynchronously on the website I'm unable to capture it with jsoup.

Does anybody knows a way around this? Am I using the right toolset? more experienced people, I bid your advice.

Comment: *"crawl some of website content"*  What is an example URL for this content?

Comment: Find yourself a package called "Fiddler" or similiar Firefox extension that will show what information is being asked for AFTER the page has loaded via Ajax. This will reveal either a secret URL or session information being passed when the page reloads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check before if the website you're crawling demands some of this list to show all contents:

- Authentication with Login/Password
- Some sort of session validation on HTTP headers
- Cookies
- Some sort of time delay to load all the contents (sites profuse on Javascript libraries, CSS and asyncronous data may need of this).
- An specific User-Agent browser
- A proxy password if, by example, you're inside a corporative network security configuration.

If anything on this list is needed, you can manage that data providing the parameters in your jsoup.connect(). Please refer the official doc.

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url