# Jsoup returns html different from web browser

Tags: jsoup

I have a `url = "http://mp3.zing.vn/tim-kiem/playlist.html?q=Bảo Thy`

> `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get()`

when I use `Jsoup` to get html. It doesn't work right. It returns the html which is different from when I use a browser. How can I solve this problem.

However, When I use url without parameters (`http://mp3.zing.vn)`, It works right.

Answer (score 2):

I have solve this problem.

```
http://mp3.zing.vn/tim-kiem/playlist.html?q=Bảo thy
```

Parameter is vietnamese word and in this case, this site uses URL encoding. So that, I have to encode all of parameters to UTF-8 encoding.

```
keyword = URLEncoder.encode(keyword,"UTF-8");
```

and the url after encode

```
http://mp3.zing.vn/tim-kiem/playlist.html?q=B%E1%BA%A3o%20thy
```

Jsoup has worked right.

Thanks for all. Close Topic.

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible that you will need to provide a cookie, session or some kind a registration method.

Please, check this:

[Advice with crawling web site content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294765/advice-with-crawling-web-site-content/11296314#11296314)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("YourURL").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
```