# Reading HTML using jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

so i am trying to get an HTML element from a website using **Jsoup**, but the HTML that i get from the **Jsoup.connect(url)** is not complete compared to the one that i get using the inspector on the website.

**EDIT :** this is the link i'm working with https://www.facebook.com/livemap#@35.831640894,24.82275312499999,2z

The numbers in the end designate the coordinates of the map, and you don't have to sign in to access the page, so there is no authentication problem

**UPDATE :**

So i have found that the element that i want does not get expanded using jsoup, is this a problem related to slow page loading ? If so, how can i make sure that **Jsoup.connect(url)** fully loads the webpage before fetching the HTML

[from inspector (the `<div id="u_0_e">` is expanded)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw4xm.png)

[from jsoup.connect (the `<div id="u_0_e">` is not expanded)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M6zr.png)

Comment: Did you try this [Jsoup returns html different from web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376731/jsoup-returns-html-different-from-web-browser) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jsoup returns html different from web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376731/jsoup-returns-html-different-from-web-browser)

Comment: i tried encoding it did not work, i posted the exact link i'm working with on my post, thanks for the help in finding a related problem though ;)

Comment: As far as I know not considering JSoup doesn't run JavaScript code. What you could do is run an embedded webview (check compatibility first), inject JavaScript once the page has finished loading which returns the HTML body in a variable and then start parsing. This method is not resource friendly and the initial startup of the WebView is slow.

Comment: @ZUNJAE this is an interesting way to solve the problem but as you said, its not that optimal, i will keep that solution mind in case i run out of options. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup dont execute javascript or jQuery events, so you will get a initial page before executing javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, this is considered a comment rather than an answer. You can still improve this by expounding your answer more by either giving an example/codes or explaining your point in details.